# Accumulating gradients in Tensorflow Eager Execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I didn't find any resources online to accumulate gradients in TensorFlow eager execution, so I coded up something like this -

```
def process(model, dataloader, optimizer):
    accum_iter = 0
    accum_grads = [tf.zeros_like(x) for x in model.trainable_variables]

    for batch in dataloader:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = compute_loss(batch, model)
        grads = tape.gradient(target=loss, sources=model.trainable_variables)

        accum_iter += 1
        if accum_iter % accum_steps == 0:
            accum_grads = [ag/accum_steps for ag in accum_grads]
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(accum_grads, model.trainable_variables))
            accum_iter = 0
        else:
            accum_grads = [g+ag for g, ag in zip(grads, accum_grads)]
```

The gradients for a batch size of 4 is quite different from the gradients accumulated twice over the batch size of 2. I assume that there is something wrong happening in the above code. Is there any mistake in the above code?